# Synonyms for Renaissance Man

Tags: synonyms

I've been poking around the net trying to find synonyms for "renaissance man" which indicates someone that is proficient at many skills. I was thinking "jack of all trades" but that has a negative connotation that the individual is not *good* at any of them, but capable. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I just haven't heard it in the right contexts, but I don't associate "jack of all trades" with a negative connotation.

Comment: @Nicole The standard idiom is "*Jack of all trades, **master of none***".

Comment: Oh. Well, that explains it :)

Comment: Eclectic? Versatile?

Comment: What about Macgyver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A single, and slightly formal, word which captures "*Renaissance man*" is "***polymath***".

From [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/polymath), for example:

> ***A polymath is a person who knows a lot about a lot of subjects.*** If your friend is not only a brilliant physics student but has also published a poetry collection and won prizes at political debates, you can describe her as a polymath.
>
> ***You can think of a polymath as a classic "Renaissance man."*** Imagine Leonardo da Vinci, for example, who was not only an amazing artist, but also an engineer, inventor, mathematician, and much more. When a person's knowledge covers many different areas, he or she is a polymath.

Again from [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/polymath):

> ***polymath***: someone who has a lot of knowledge about many different subjects

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymath):

> ***polymath***: someone who knows a lot about many different things

And the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/Polymath):

> ***Polymath*** is Greek for renaissance person; someone with the ability to do many remarkable things because they are experts across many disciplines.

Comment: I thought about it, but polymath is more about knowing rather than doing..or not?

Comment: @Josh61 DaVinci is the classic example of a *polymath*; the word is most often colocated with his name.  Do you think of him as a pure "thinker" or was he a "doer"?

Comment: Really? I would have said *Renaissance man* or *genius* were the words most associated with Leonardo.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Other way around.  The person most associated with the word "polymath" is Leonardo. But "polymath" is not the word most associated with the person.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a slightly different tack from "renaissance man", which focuses on *broad learning* and education; a high-brow appellation, there is the category of a "generally useful" individual.

This is a "gets done whatever needs to get done" sort of characteristic: the human analog to a Swiss Army knife.  For that, you have a couple of options:

> ***General factotum***
>
> [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factotum):
>
> 1. *a person whose job involves doing many different types of work*
> 2. *a person having many diverse activities or responsibilities*
>
> [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/general-factotum)
>
> *a person who does all sorts of jobs; general assistant*

and the more down-to-Earth:

> ***Guy Friday*** / ***Gal Friday***:
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guy+friday)
>
> *a person who acts as a general assistant in a business office or to an executive and has a wide variety of especially secretarial and clerical duties.*

and finally the political and slightly intimidating:

> ***Body man***
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_man)
>
> *A body man is, in U.S. political jargon, a personal assistant to a politician or political candidate. A body man accompanies the politician or candidate virtually everywhere, often arranging lodging, transportation or meals, and providing companionship comprising providing snacks, a cell phone, and any other necessary assistance.*

Comment: That is also called *spin doctor*.

Comment: @Josh61 Nah. A spin doctor is a spokesperson. A Guy Friday / General Factotum / Body Man / Valet is behind the scenes. The man behind the man, if you will (or gentleman's gentleman, if I remember my *My Remains of the Day*).

Comment: Spin doctor:  a person (such as a political aide) whose job involves trying to control the way something (such as an important event) is described to the public in order to influence what people think about it.http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin%20doctor

Comment: @Josh61 Precisely. That's very different from the persons and roles described in my answer. Those people are *not* public facing; they serve only the man himself, not the organization.

Comment: Yep, not much of a renaissance in both cases I'd say!

Comment: @Josh61 Haha, I posted this because you said, on my previous answer, that it was too intellectually focused and not descriptive of a "doer". This answer is focused on roles that are multidisciplinary "doers" (which is different from what a *spin doctor* is).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idiom which if you're a film buff you'll recognize instantly. The homonymous play (1954) is set in 16th-century Tudor England and is based on the true life of Sir Thomas More, of whom a contemporary once said:

> More is a man of an angel's wit and singular learning. I know not his fellow. For where is the man of that gentleness, lowliness and affability? And, as time requireth, a man of marvelous mirth and pastimes, and sometime of as sad gravity. A man for all seasons."

The play was subsequently made into a beautiful period film in 1966.

> **A man for all seasons**
>
> a man who is very successful in many different types of activity
>
> - *He's chairman of a large chemicals company as well as a successful painter - really [a man for all seasons](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+man+for+all+seasons)*.

Answer (score -1):

["A man of many parts"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/a-man-of-many-parts), or just ["a man of parts"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man_of_parts).

> - A man with great ability in many different areas:
>
>   - he was a man of parts—a painter, Egyptologist, and biographer (ODO)